# Are there any ground truth data available for San Francisco?

Tags: data, united-states

I'm working on the [algorithm in this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5659970&refinements%3D4225530238%26filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A5719225%29) and I've modified it a bit. Now in order to quantify the accuracy of my algorithm with this algorithm, I need ground truth data of SanFrancisco.
[image]
Which has at least five classes:

- buildings (if detailed, it'll be better)
- sea (if detailed better)
- fir trees of the vegetated area
- spruce trees of the vegetated area
- pine trees of the vegetated areas
  (Generally, it would be better to have a ground truth as detailed as possible).
  Do you know such ground truth or any useful rasterized map to be able to be able to make a ground truth with optical imagery?

---

Maybe this question is a better fit for opendata.

Comment: Have you seen [SF OpenData](https://data.sfgov.org/)? Not sure if they possess ground truth data but they do have quite detailed data on [buildings](https://data.sfgov.org/Housing-and-Buildings/Building-Footprints/6p33-sdua) and [trees](https://data.sfgov.org/Energy-and-Environment/SF-Urban-Tree-Canopy/55pv-5zcc).

Comment: @Joseph and I actually have found some data. including [data1](http://goo.gl/hq95gK),[data2](http://goo.gl/5amUwR) and [data3](http://goo.gl/H98yyK). But all of them are for buildings. When it reaches to  national parks, etc. there's no data about inside them. including type of trees